# How to set different ANSI codepages for different legacy Windows applications?

Tags: windows-7, windows, unicode, localization

Unfortunately there is still a lot of Windows applications that use legacy character encodings instead of proper Unicode. Windows control panel allows to choose one codepage for all of them but I use legacy apps written in different languages (Russian, Czech and others) and would like to choose different codepages independently for every non-unicode app. I can remember there was a special tool for this (by Microsoft) but can't remember what was its name and where could it be downloaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found it myself, sharing for just a case anybody else may need it too:

It's Microsoft AppLocale and it can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13209).

There also is a quick introduction into installing and using it [here](http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/microsoft/applocale/).